JSON Syntax Exception when parsing String containing JSON Array using TypeToken via GSON
Am having trouble parsing String containing a JSON array as a List using TypeToken via GSON in my Kotlin program.
dependencies section inside gradle.build.kts:
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

The raw JSON looks something similar to this:
{
    "message": [
        "https://sample.com/images/apple.jpg",
        "https://sample.com/images/banana.jpg",
        "https://sample.com/images/orange.jpg"
    ],
    "status": "success"
}

Kotlin code that throws the exception/stack trace:
val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                        .disableHtmlEscaping()
                        .serializeNulls()
                        .create()

val fruitPictures = object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type

// It fails here:
val fruitPicturesList = gson.fromJson<List<String>>(jsonStr, fruitPictures) 

Stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#unexpected-json-structure
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1372)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1262)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1171)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1137)
    at com.myapp.jsonutils.FruitImages.run(FruitImages.kt:6)

    at com.myapp.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:9)
    at java.base@21/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#unexpected-json-structure
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.unexpectedTokenError(JsonReader.java:1768)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:430)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:59)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1361)


Your JSON represents a single object {} but you're trying to deserialize to List<String> which would expect a JSON array []. The error states that the parser was expecting [ but got { instead

recommendation: don't use gson in kotlin projects

@Pawel - Why not?

GSON is outdated and in maintenance mode for couple of years already. Main issue with it is that it's entirely reflection based so performance is poor and it sometimes causes weird behaviour like forcefully spawning classes without invoking their constructors. Other one is it has completely no support for Kotlin so it does not recognize or respect metadata like nullability and default values which is really problematic. E.g. with data classes (which are ideal for mapping values to) you can end up with non-nullable property that holds a null value and crashes your program when accessed.

@Pawel - Thanks for the explanation... What's the preferred JSON deserialization library for Kotlin?
